# reading sensors data in a Drone GUI

Tags: c#

I'm designing a GUI that receives voltage and current readings from a drone and displays it in text books.
I receive data in the form (H,0.00,0.00,)
I used the split function to read the values.
but when I start the program I get the error message
"system.indexOutOfRangeException:"index was outside the bound of the array"
I'm a beginner in C#. any suggestions on how to resolve the issue

```
...using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace G_Station
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        string ArduData = "";
        string[] pot;
        string current = "";
        string voltage = "";
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void ConnectBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                serialPort1.PortName = PortCmb.Text;
                serialPort1.BaudRate = Convert.ToInt32(BaudCmb.Text);
                serialPort1.Parity = System.IO.Ports.Parity.None;
                serialPort1.StopBits = System.IO.Ports.StopBits.One;
                serialPort1.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(28591);
                serialPort1.DataBits = 8;
                serialPort1.Open();
                ConnectBtn.Enabled = false;
                DisconnectBtn.Enabled = true;
                timer1.Enabled = true;
              
            }
            catch (Exception errName)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(errName.ToString());
            }
        }

        private void DisconnectBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                //serialPort1.PortName = PortCmb.Text;
                //serialPort1.BaudRate = Convert.ToInt32(BaudCmb.Text);
                serialPort1.Parity = System.IO.Ports.Parity.None;
                serialPort1.StopBits = System.IO.Ports.StopBits.One;
                serialPort1.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(28591);
                serialPort1.DataBits = 8;
                serialPort1.Close();
                ConnectBtn.Enabled = true;
                DisconnectBtn.Enabled = false;
                timer1.Enabled = false;
            }
            catch (Exception errName)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(errName.ToString());
            }
        }

        private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            
        }
        

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (serialPort1.BytesToRead < 3 )
            {
                ArduData = "H,00.0,00.0,"; 
            }
            else
            {
                ArduData = serialPort1.ReadLine();
            }
            pot = ArduData.Split(',');

            
                current = pot[2];
                voltage = pot[1];
            
            VoltLbl.Text = current;
            CurrentLbl.Text = voltage;
            
        }
 
        private void VoltLbl_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           
        }

        private void CurrentLbl_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}...
```

Comment: What is the value after ` ArduData = serialPort1.ReadLine();`? I suspect it either doesn't have any commas in, or doesn't have enough to satisfy your split and subsequent reading of the array

Comment: The data is sent in the form H,00.0,00.0, sometimes it skips a few readings and suspect that is the source of the problem.

Comment: So, you need to add some checks to your code instead of blindly splitting a string and expecting a valid array.

Comment: do you have any suggestions? I tried to use an if statement but it didn't work.         it was like if port.bytestoread <1 then C=0 V=0       else c=data.split v=data.split

Comment: Output the value of the `ArduData` to a file or console. Check the value that caused the problem. At the moment, you are making too  many assumptions. As stated, I expect that `ArduData` is either empty or doesn't contain enough commas to satisfy your split code.

Comment: Also, when you say "my attempt didn't work", you should add that code to your question as an edit.

Comment: my attempt is the code that I'm showing here. I'm sorry I'm still learning how to do this

Comment: I don't think ...Ardudata... is always empty the text box sometimes shows a couple of readings before stopping the program.

Comment: "I don't think" is an example of your assumptions. Create a logging mechanism so that you **know**. The only test you have is to see if the number of bytes to read is<3. If the number of bytes is, e.g., 4 then your split will still run and fail

Comment: I will try to do that. and if you have any suggestions I'll be grateful.

Comment: do you know of a better way to check if my port has the data and a better way to stop the splitting?